# How to remove native navigation bar elevation through Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to get rid of a faint divider between the native navigation buttons on the bottom of the screen and the content of my app.

This is what I have - you can see a very faint divider between the navigation buttons and the bottom navigation bar of my app. Is it elevation? Shadow?

[image]

But this is what I want (this is the Android Slack app) - all same colour.
[image]

In my app, I'm explicitly setting the bottom navigation bar to white, as well as use the `accompanist` library to set the navigation bar to white, like so:

```kotlin
BottomNavigation(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White),
        backgroundColor = Color.White,
        elevation = 0.dp,
    )

...

    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    SideEffect {
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
            color = Color.White,
        )
    }
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the issue - it looks like if the `Scaffold` is wrapped in a `ModalBottomSheetLayout`, it will do weird colour changes like this to the `BottomNavigation`.

In order to avoid this, you can do:

```kotlin
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetElevation = 0.dp,
        bottomSheetNavigator = bottomSheetNavigator,
    ) { ... }
```

and the "faint divider" goes away!

The `ModalBottomSheetLayout` is from the accompanist library as well - `com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-material`

Comment: Worked for me as well, been looking everywhere for this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite reproduce this issue, when I attempt to set background of `BottomNavigation` by using Modifier. It does not affect anything (still using default purple primary color from material color I think), but when I try to set background by parameter backgroundColor, still there is no `faint divider` between the system navigation bar and the app navigation bar as you can see here.

[image]

Can you show me the detail implementation of your `BottomNavigation` and what device did you use?

Comment: Thank you for testing! I also can't reproduce this in a sample app. The `BottomNavigation` implementation doesn't seem to matter - even if I leave it empty, I can still see the divider :( Just not sure what in the app set up can be impacting this. I'm using a Pixel 5, Android 13